# How to prioritize related game entity components?

Tags: unity, ai, movement, component-based

I want to make a game where you have to run over a bunch of zombies with your car. When moving around, the zombies have a few things to take into consideration:

- When there's no player around they might just roam about randomly. And even when some other component dictates a specific direction, they should wobble to the left and right randomly (like drunk people). This implies a small, random, deviation in their movement.
- They should avoid static obstacles. When they see they are headed towards a wall, they should reorient themselves.
- They should avoid the car. They should try to predict where the car will be based on its velocity and try to move out of the way.
- When they can, they should try to get near the player.

All these types of decisions they have to do seem like they should be implemented in different components. But how should I manage them? How can I give different components different weights that reflect the importance of each decision (in a given situation)?

I would need some other component that acts as a manager, but do you have any tips on how I should implement it? Or maybe there's a better solution?...

Comment: First things first.  There are approximately one megazillion "component based" ways of designing code, which one are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHughes I'm using Unity.

Comment: I've added "unity" and "AI" to your tags with the hope that it brings in experienced answers because Unity is a popular kit.

Comment: I'm not really sure if you need different component for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to separate the AI and the actions the creature can take.  The "wobbliness" you desire can be implemented in a `MoveForward` function, relieving the AI from having to worry about it.

Secondly, I recommend a `behavior-based` AI.  You keep a list of behaviors, probably subclasses of a `BaseBehavior` object, sorted in the order of importance.  In your case, it'd probably be something like the following:

- Kill player
- Avoid car
- Avoid wall
- Move towards player
- Wander

Each behavior would have a function called `WantsActive`, which would return `true` if the behavior needed to be used.  (For example, `KillPlayerBehavior` would only return `true` when the player was in range.)  Every time `Update` is called, you loop through the list of behaviors, calling `WantsActive` on each and stopping when one returns `true.`

This one would have its `Execute` function called, resulting in the creature performing that behavior.  If you wanted it to be able to perform multiple behaviors in one frame, you could even check the return value of `Execute`, with `true` meaning "no more actions" and `false` meaning "continue with next behavior."  When the manager got `false` in this case, it'd just resume the `WantsActive` loop where it left off.

This approach is nicely object-oriented, it avoids hard-coding behaviors within the `Creature` class, and it is very easily extendable with new behavior classes, even at runtime.  The same manager can work with any number of different behavior combinations.

You might want to Google [subsumption architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsumption_architecture).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simplistic finite-state machine solution (ZombieBrainModule.Update() specifically) set up in a components-based style, but it should get you on the right track. Note that I use the word "module" and not "component" below so as to avoid confusion with Unity's built-in components, which as gajet suggested, are not needed.

```
using UnityEngine;

//drop this on each zombie-representative GameObject in the Unity IDE
public class ZombieController : MonoBehaviour
{
    ZombieBrainModule ai;
    LifeModule life;
    WeaponModule weapon;
    //etc.

    void Start()
    {
        ai = new ZombieBrainModule(this.transform, life, weapon);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ai.Update(); //think about what I, Zombie, intend to do (in this case, motion + weapon actions) and store these
        life.Update(); //eg. for regeneration?
        //etc.
    }

}

public abstract class Module
{
    public abstract void Update();
}

using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieBrainModule
{
    private LifeModule life;
    private WeaponModule weapon;

    public ZombieBrainModule(this.transform, life, weapon);
    {
        this.life = life;
        this.weapon = weapon;
        this.transform = transform;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        //Pseudocode; a very simplistic finite state machine.

        if near a wall
            avoid nearest wall;
        else
            if player nearby
                if player in car
                    run away from player;               
                else
                    if life.remaining > 25% //clever zombie!
                        go toward player;
                        if player within firing range
                            weapon.fire;
                    else
                        run away from player;
            else
                wander;
    }
    //to keep things simple, I avoided heavy class hierarchies, but you could easily use a base Entity class which holds refs to the various modules, from which Zombie and Player would derive.
```

**Note** This excludes the zombie from avoiding walls when he is doing something else. If you want wall avoidance to also happen whilst the zombie is avoiding the player or chasing them, you will need to take some sort of an average of the two vector directions the zombie is being pulled toward. For instance, you might aim for a total float weighting of 1.0f, so you apply your wall avoidance weighted as 0.3f of that, and your player seek (or avoid) as 0.7f of that. After normalising the influence vectors (call 'em `wallInfluence` and `playerInfluence`), multiply each respective one by it's fractional weight, then sum the two vectors for the final motion vector by which you will update your zombie's `transform.position`. Some of these influence weights may vary continuously based on other factors, eg. proximity to the player or his one-and-a-half tons of roaring 70's muscle car.